# How to clear NextJs GetStaticPaths cache / "unpublish" a dynamic route?

Tags: typescript, next.js, contentful

I think this is quite a vanilla question but I can't find anything on Google.

I'm learning NextJs (using TypeScript) and I've got a site successfully working with dynamic routes, SSR, and incremental regeneration all setup and deployed to Vercel. Here's an example of the `GetStaticProps` and `GetStaticPaths` code in my dynamic route handler:

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    const routes = new CmsHelper().GetRoutes();

    const paths = (await routes).items.map((item, index, items) => {
        return item.fields.urlPath;
    })

    return {
        paths: paths,
        fallback: 'blocking',
    };
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const urlParts = context.params?.url as string[] || [];
    const urlPath = `/${urlParts.join('/')}`;
    const article = await new CmsHelper().GetArticle(urlPath);
    return {
        props: {
            article
        },
        revalidate: 10,
    }
}
```

If I request a *new* path that was published in the cms after build time, it successfully regenerates on the server and returns the page.

So far so good.

However, if I *unpublish* a route in my CMS... it is still returned by the app, unless I rebuild and redeploy (or otherwise cause the process to restart, in dev).

So my question is: how do I dynamically cause NextJs to remove a dynamic route from its GetStaticPaths cache?

I understand that `GetStaticProps` is going to be called at most once every 10 seconds because of the `revalidate` configuration. But as far as I know, `GetStaticPaths` will only be called if a request comes in from a route that is not currently cached(?)

In other words, for an integration with a headless CMS, how can I support *unpublishing or renaming* pages with NextJs without triggering a rebuild/deploy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this approach described [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10960#discussioncomment-1201).

Also providing the code here for reference purposes.

```
// pages/blog/[slug].js

import {useRouter} from 'next/router'
import DefaultErrorPage from 'next/error'

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // fetch data from CMS through params
  const post = await getBlogItem(params.slug)
  return {
    props: {
      post
    }
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    fallback: true,
    paths: []
  }
}

export default function MyPage({post}) {
  const router = useRouter()

  if(router.isFallback) {
     return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }

  // This includes setting the noindex header because static files always return a status 200 but the rendered not found page page should obviously not be indexed
  if(!post) {
    return <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
      </Head>
      <DefaultErrorPage statusCode={404} />
    </>
  }

  return <h1>{post.title}</h1>
}
```

So, instead of deleting/clearing the cache, maybe try to handle successfully that the content you are fetching is "unpublished" and if so, you can display a `404 Not found` page or something of your choice.

Something like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {

    const {params: {id}} = context

    let data;
    try {
        data = await httpClient...
    } catch (err) {
        if (not err is caused due to content being unpublished){
            // re throw it
            throw err;
        }
        // Else handle it gracefully
        data = null;
    }

    return {
        props: {
            data,
        },
        revalidate: 1
    };
}
```

and then on your View:

```
export default function Data(props) {
    const {data} = props;

    const router = useRouter()

    // If the page is not yet generated, this will be displayed
    // initially until getStaticProps() finishes running
    if (router.isFallback) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    if (!data) {
        return (
            <>
                <Head>
                    <meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>
                </Head>
                <DefaultErrorPage statusCode={404}/>
            </>
        )
    }

    return <DataView {...data} />;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar but different problem: Deploying my project generated URL from the data, but I couldn't add any new URLs when the data in the DB changed.

The key to my problem was that I was setting fallback to false in my getStaticPaths method. When I set it to true the production deploy started behaving like my local development build.

I see that you're passing a string value for your fallback property. You might try using a boolean value as described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required

Comment: Actually: check out [revalidate: 1](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) as returned by getStaticProps.
- fallback: true fixes new URLs
- revalidate: 1 fixes old URLs

Answer (score -1):

With Next.js 12.2 released in summer 2022 you can use On-Demand Incremental Static Regeneration to update generated pages on demand, i.e. when you publish changes in your headless CMS and use its webhook features.

```
// pages/api/revalidate.js

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // Check for secret to confirm this is a valid request
  if (req.query.secret !== process.env.MY_SECRET_TOKEN) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' })
  }

  try {
    // this should be the actual path not a rewritten path
    // e.g. for "/blog/[slug]" this should be "/blog/post-1"
    await res.revalidate('/path-to-revalidate')
    return res.json({ revalidated: true })
  } catch (err) {
    // If there was an error, Next.js will continue
    // to show the last successfully generated page
    return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating')
  }
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation